# OpenSSL's 's_client' command returns error code 61

Tags: linux, openssl

I leased a private remote server. I have installed mattermost on that server and have configured it to use TLS. I created a ssl certificate/key pair and have configured the app to retrieve these files.

I can't connect to the server and the tool I am using to get some info on one part of the chain of dependencies (the ssl certificates) doesn't give me output that I understand.

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect site_url:443    
140704689604160:error:0200203D:system library:connect:Connection refused:crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
140704689604160:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=61
```

I have searched on Google and discovered that Citrix SSL interprets that code as indicating that the certificate is not trusted.
I am uncertain about the connection between this and OpenSSL.

Could someone provide clarification on the meaning of that error code for OpenSSL?

Comment: That actually suggests port 443 is not "open" on "site_url" - though, I wouldn't be surprised if the issue is an untrusted certificate - is your `ssl certificate/key pair` *self signed*?

Comment: yes the ssl certificate/key pair is self signed

Comment: then how does openssl know to trust it?

Comment: fair point. This is the first time I am doing this. I presumed that I could use a self signed certificate. I read something about processing the certificate with another command line tool as to trust it in a separate search but it wasn't clear.

Comment: I'm not sure, perhaps the `-cert <file>` command line argument may help - I've never used `openssl s_client` so I'm a newb at that :p

Comment: This is a network problem and nothing to do with the cert/key pair. s_client has been unable to even make a TCP connection to the site - so the certificate has not yet been sent from the server to the client. errno 61 is not an OpenSSL error per se, its just the system error "ECONNREFUSED"

Comment: Since it looks like the error is `connect:Connection refused`, are there any firewalls not permitting access to port 443?

Comment: I do think the port is open. When I run `netstat -tulpn` or `lsof` I see that the port is being listened to. I presume that means for external traffic

Comment: I can see that port 443 is open by using Iptables
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443